# $location.host() breaks angular tests. How to mock it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, mocking, location

I know that there are similar questions here, but I've tried them all without success.

I have a factory, that fetches texts for my application:

```
    __resolveAngularModules__('checkoutWeb.interconnections', ['ngCookies', 'angular-hal', 'LocalStorageModule'])
  .factory('msgData', ['$http', 'msgMock', '$location', function ($http, msgMock, $location) {
      var url;
      switch ($location.host()) {
        case 'localhost':
          url = '/texts/commerce?version=1';
          break;
        case 'www2-dev.xxx.com':
          url = '/texts/commerce?version=2';
          break;
      }
    return $http.get(url, {
      headers: {
        'ClientId': 'some-id'
      }
    }).then(function (response) {
      return response;
    }, function (response) {
      Raven.captureException(new Error("Failed to load texts with status: " + response.status + " " + response.statusText));
      return msgMock;
    });
  }]);
```

So, if I use directly '/blahblah' in $http.get(), tests are ok, but if I'm trying to use logic described above, I'm getting errors in tests.

I've tried to inject `$location` and use `spyOn($location.prototype, "host").andReturn("localhost");` in `beforeEach()` block, or use `$browser.url`, but both didn't work for me.

What am I missing? I'm stuck wit this... Will appreciate any help..

UPDATE:
Just tried solution from [here](http://www.ngroutes.com/questions/AU03u-COX0lsqxww8SXA/angularjs-mock-location-path-with-spyon-for-a-unit-test.html). This example is very similar to mine, but solution still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help in advance.

So my test looks like this now:

```
describe('directive: accordionDir', function() {
  var accordionDir, element, scope, $location, $rootScope;

  beforeEach(module('checkoutWeb'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, $compile, $httpBackend, _msgMock_, _$location_) {

    $rootScope =_$rootScope_;
    scope = $rootScope;
    $location = _$location_;
    spyOn($location, 'host').andReturn('localhost');
    scope.msgData = _msgMock_;

    $httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/open/texts/commerce?version=1').respond(scope.fmsData);

    element ='<div accordion-dir><a href="#" class="twister"><div class="details"></div></a><div class="answer" style="display: none;"></div></div>';
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
  }));

  it('should call $location host: ', function () {
    inject(function(accordionDir){
      expect($location.host()).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
  });
```

Erros stack:

> PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) directive: accordionDir should call
>   $location host:  FAILED   TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object
>   (evaluating 'parsed.protocol')
>         at urlIsSameOrigin (c:/source/checkout-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14560)
>         at sendReq (c:/source/checkout-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8419)
>         at c:/source/checkout-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8146
>         at c:/source/checkout-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11682
>         at c:/source/checkout-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11682
>         at c:/source/checkout-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11768
>         at c:/source/checkout-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12811
>         at c:/source/checkout-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12623
>         at c:/source/checkout-web/src/app/additional-directives/accordion-directve_test.js:18
>         at invoke (c:/source/checkout-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3965)
>         at workFn (c:/source/checkout-web/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2177)
>     undefined   Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   accordionDirProvider <- accordionDir
>     http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/unpr?p0=accordionDirProvider%20%3C-%20accordionDir
>         at c:/source/checkout-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3801
>         at getService (c:/source/checkout-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3929)
>         at c:/source/checkout-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3806
>         at getService (c:/source/checkout-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3929)
>         at invoke (c:/source/checkout-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3956)
>         at workFn (c:/source/checkout-web/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2177)
>         at c:/source/checkout-web/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2163
>         at c:/source/checkout-web/src/app/additional-directives/accordion-directve_test.js:25
>     undefined

Answer (score 0):

Didn't manage to solve this problem with $location use. So my solution to get working tests here was to use window.location.hostname instead of $location in msgData factory. With window.location.hostname you don't need extra code in tests. Cheers!